# How to get related field value from database in odoo 11 and postgresql?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, odoo-11

I am trying to get a related field value from database, but it showing **column 'column_name' does not exist**.

When i try to find out the value of product_id or using join to find the common data between sale.order and product.product Model . but it showing column 'column_name' does not exist.

In sale.order model the field defination is like

```
product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', related='order_line.product_id', string='Product')
```

But when i try to join two table like below code to fetch all data as per product, like below code.

```
select coalesce(p.name,'Unassigned Product'), count(*) from sale_order o left join product_product p on o.product_id = p.id where o.state = 'sale' group by p.name;
```

It showing below error,

```
column o.product_id does not exist
LINE 1: ... from sale_order o left join product_product p on o.product_...
```

When i try to get data from sale_order  table like below code.

```
select product_id from sale_order;
```

It showing below error.

```
column "product_id" does not exist
```

Can any one help me to get that value.

Answer (score 2):

To access a related field from database , you have to use the `store=True` , keyword.
Rewrite your field definition as,

```
product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', related='order_line.product_id', string='Product', store=True)
```

and uninstall and install the module.